# Artificial Immune System (AIS) Java Framework

Tags: java, frameworks, evolutionary-algorithm

Is anyone aware of a reliable AIS framework, implemented in java? I am going to be working on an AIS inspired project soon and don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Thanks.

Comment: For those who don't know what AIS, can you clarify what you have in mind and what you plan to use it for?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_immune_system . at a high level, I will be taking lots of sports data (player statistics) and modelling n seasons, in order to find a successful 'type' of team. My end product, will be able to identify a successful 'type' of team.